# I installed a thicker 1TB hard drive in my laptop, could this cause more heating to the motherboard?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard

I searched for a similar question around the web, but I couldn't find anything. I have Lenovo G580 and I swapped the built-in Seagate 500GB hard drive for WD Blue 1TB. The thicker WD Blue drive fits just fine, but it's a couple of millimeter thicker. I'm worrying that since hard drive is positioned right next to the motherboard that the thicker drive will transfer more heath to the motherboard. Can this really happen, or am I just paranoid?

My current temperatures according to Speccy during light use (text editing) are:
CPU: 46°
MB: 45° C
WD Drive: 38° C

I'm not sure, but I think that those are normal, since the drive fits into the hard drive bay, does it mean that the laptop can support it just fine? If the engineers thought that it couldn't support thicker drives, we wouldn't be able to install them, right?

Thanks for the help...

Comment: "*I'm worrying that since hard drive is positioned right next to the motherboard that the thicker drive will transfer more heath to the motherboard.*" This sounds like nonsense. Why would a thicker drive transfer more heat?

Comment: @David Schwartz Well I thought that since it's closer to the motherboard, or since it might even be pressing up against it, that it's easier for heath to transfer from the hard drive to the motherboard. It made sense it my head, the closer you are to a source of heath, the more heath you get. That's how physics works, doesn't it?

Comment: Physics says that a component that uses a given amount of power (watts) _must_ produce that equivalent amount of heat (unless some of that power is being used to do actual _work_, like lifting weights, which doesn't apply here). It doesn't matter whether it's physically in contact with something else or not. Watts in = Watts out, regardless of how much airspace separates it from anything else. (n.b.: There is no trailing "h" in the word "heat".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *standard* for laptop hard drives for many years was 9mm and newer drives are 7mm. I would expect that the system was designed around a 9mm drive if it even fits in. You can generally use a 9mm drive in a system with a slot for it, but 7mm drives are getting more common, so they are sometimes used instead. If your new drive *didn't* fit, you'd have issues.

Being designed with a 9mm drive includes things like cooling. The snugger fit may even end up letting the HDD use the laptop's internal frame to spread heat, and keep it more secure in place.

Those temperatures do look fine and within acceptable parameters, and even if the motherboard was heating up more, you shouldn't face any issues of it within the design life of the laptop

Comment: Agreed. What you need to look at is the drive's power consumption, not the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

It is the quality of the hardware not the size that causes the issues. So no that is not a problem.